# Add cartopy coastlines to subplots

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, cartopy

I am having trouble adding the cartopy coastlines into sublots. For example, ax.coastlines('10m', linewidth = 1.5, color = 'black'). I also want it to match the image extent of the plots. I am plotting a 3d array, where each array on the z axis is a different image. Below is the code

```
img_extent = (lon.min(), lon.max(), lat.min(), lat.max())

# Create a figure
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols=4, subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()},figsize=(16,14))


# add coastlines
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent(img_extent, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines('10m', linewidth=1.5, color = 'black')

# Make the image

axarr[0,0].imshow(first_lag[0],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[0,1].imshow(first_lag[12],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[0,2].imshow(first_lag[24],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[0,3].imshow(first_lag[36],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

axarr[1,0].imshow(second_lag[0],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[1,1].imshow(second_lag[12],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[1,2].imshow(second_lag[24],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[1,3].imshow(second_lag[36],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

axarr[2,0].imshow(third_lag[0],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[2,1].imshow(third_lag[12],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[2,2].imshow(third_lag[24],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[2,3].imshow(third_lag[36],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

axarr[3,0].imshow(third_lag[0],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[3,1].imshow(third_lag[12],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[3,2].imshow(third_lag[24],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axarr[3,3].imshow(third_lag[36],  vmin = 0, vmax = 1000, cmap = 'viridis', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.get_xticks()
#plt.colorbar()
#plt.title(title)

gl = ax.gridlines(color="white", alpha=0.4, linestyle="dotted", draw_labels=True, dms=True, x_inline=False, y_inline=False)
gl.top_labels = False 
gl.right_labels = False
```

However the results show this:
[image]

I want the outline of Puerto Rico on each plot. I am really lost, thank you.

Comment: Use `axarr[0,0]` and so on in stead of `ax`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare your code with mine and make correction to yours. Here is my code that works well and produces the plot similar to what you are after.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# settings
h, w = 12, 10        # for raster image
nrows, ncols = 3, 2  # array of sub-plots
figsize = [10, 10]   # figure size, inches

myproj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
extent = [-68, -65, 16.7, 19.5]

# create figure (fig), and array of axes (ax)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=figsize, subplot_kw={'projection': myproj})

# plot simple raster image on each sub-plot
for i, axi in enumerate(ax.flat):
    # i runs from 0 to (nrows*ncols-1)
    # axi is equivalent with ax[rowid][colid]
    img = np.random.randint(10, size=(h,w))
    axi.imshow(img, extent=extent, alpha=0.25)
    # get indices of row/column
    rowid = i // ncols
    colid = i % ncols
    # write row/col indices as axes' title for identification
    axi.set_title("Row:"+str(rowid)+", Col:"+str(colid))
    axi.coastlines('50m')
    axi.set_xlim(extent[0], extent[1])
    axi.set_ylim(extent[2], extent[3])

    gl = axi.gridlines(color="black", alpha=0.4, linestyle="dotted", draw_labels=True, \
                       dms=False, x_inline=False, y_inline=False)
    gl.top_labels = False 
    gl.right_labels = False 

plt.show()
```

[image: rico]

Comment: Thank you so much! I do have a question though-where is the white transparent overlay coming from? Edit: Nvm, its from the alpha = 0.5. Thank you so much again!